# Create HotKey to toggle program on/off using .ps1 PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am using .ps1 PowerShell script code to toggle programs on and off using a hotkey set up with a shortcut to the .ps1 file. I am using a scheduled task because this program is required to be run by admin. My code is intended to check if the program is already running by checking if the process exists. If it does not start process and if it does then stop the process.

Here is the code:

```
$ProcessActive = Get-Process UltraSearch.exe -Module -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if ($ProcessActive -eq $null) {
    Start-Scheduledtask -TaskName "UAC\Hide UAC"  
} else {
    Stop-Process UltraSearch.exe
}
```

The process starts but then when I hit the hotkey to run the script again it does not stop the process.
It doesn't seem to be able to find that process but when I check Process Explorer it is exactly as I have written it.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing .exe from get-process as below and change stop-process command.

```
    $ProcessActive = Get-Process UltraSearch -Module -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if ($ProcessActive -eq $null) {
        Start-Scheduledtask -TaskName "UAC\Hide UAC"  
    } else {
        Stop-Process $ProcessActive
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I tried and this is what I have now and the error it is giving me.$ProcessActive = Get-Process UltraSearch -Module -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 
if($ProcessActive -eq $null)
{
 Start-Scheduledtask -TaskName "Hide UAC"
}
else
{ 
Stop-Process $ProcessActive 
}

Comment: Start-Scheduledtask : The system cannot find the file specified.
At C:\Users\jerra\Desktop\Keyboard_Scripts\Tultrasearch.ps1:6 char:2
+  Start-Scheduledtask -TaskName "Hide UAC"
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (PS_ScheduledTask:Root/Microsoft/...S_ScheduledTask) [Start-ScheduledTask], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80070002,Start-ScheduledTask

Comment: NVM thank you for your help. I forgot that I had to reinstall windows so my Scheduled Task is no longer there. I think we are all set! :-) Thank you.